# The command "C:\Main\Src\.nuget\nuget.exe restore -SolutionDirectory ..\" exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, tfsbuild

I've been struggling with getting NuGet to work for well over a week now. I finally got it to work on local builds, but not on TFS 2013 builds. I narrowed it down to NuGet not happening during team builds, but then when I added

```
$(SolutionDir).nuget\nuget.exe restore -SolutionDirectory ..\
```

to the pre-build event on my first project in the build order and I get this error.  And if I execute that command from the command line in the solution directory it works fine.
It builds locally fine, but on the build server I get this "code 1" error. Very helpful Grrrrr!  So I opened the source that TFS gets before the build and tried to doing a local build on the builds server and I get the same error (even though it works fine on my local machine). I tried increased verbosity on the team build but that just shows the same error. Sorry - I've googled this error and found many responses, but nothing that has helped...

BTW, when I run the version of nuget.exe in the solution it's version 3.4.3.855.

Comment: Same here.  I also get this error if I run `msbuild` on the solution on my PC (from a command prompt).  But if I run `nuget restore` -- from the same command prompt -- it works.

Answer (score 2):

To enable restore NuGet package with TFS XAML build, please try to follow below steps:

1. In VS IDE, go to **Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager** -> enable Allow NuGet to download missing packages.
2. **Delete** NuGet.exe and NuGet.targets files from .nuget folder. Be sure these two files are deleted from version control as well.
3. **Remove** the following tags from .proj file:

```html
    1. <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>

    2.<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />  

    3. <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">  
        <PropertyGroup>
            <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, 
    see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
    </Target>
```

More details please refer this step by step tutorial：[Auto restore Nuget packages with TFS Build the right way](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/09/14/auto-restore-nuget-packages-with-tfs-build-the-right-way.aspx)

Comment: OK @Patrick-MSFT - I'm giving this a try. Just one question. So I did what you said and went to Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> then disabled Allow NuGet to download missing packages and then saved all and no changes were pended. How can changing this affect the project build if there are no changes to the projects when you make this selection?

Comment: @Ben_G Sorry, couldn't get your point. Sometime when using NuGet packages, it may need additional packages as a reference. With  Allow NuGet to download missing packages. During installation of the main package, if it’s unable to install the dependent packages, Visual Studio will allows you to auto download missing packages.

Comment: my question was how does a setting in my desktop VS change a build if nothing is checked in?

Comment: OK @Patrick-MSFT - I tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work. Now it's just failing to do the NuGet at all. I thought this might be related to the build using the wrong template, so I changed the template to TFVCTemplate.12.xaml (and thereby lost all of my msbuild parameters which is a whole new headeach ;-), but that hasn't helped either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT. So I found some additional .csproj files with the restorepackages set to true so I deleted those references and now I get:  This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is C:\Builds\TFS\WebApps\src\WebApps\Main\Src\\.nuget\NuGet.targets. Any other ideas? I also changed to the Build process template TfvcTemplate.12.xaml, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: @Ben_G Afraid you are mixing up some solutions to do the nuget restore from google, which may cause the issue. Suggest you do a new clean test, and try it again. More detail steps and info have added an answer in your newly question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700823/nuget-auto-package-restore-just-will-not-work-for-me-on-my-build-server/45713031#45713031