# NuGet auto-package restore just will not work for me on my build server

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package-restore

I'm at wits end here. I've tried everything I can find to get NuGet to restore my packages on the TFS build server and nothing seems to work. (The latest changes I checked in I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680811/the-command-c-main-src-nuget-nuget-exe-restore-solutiondirectory-exited/45690012?noredirect=1#comment78354565_45690012)). I have read a lot about problems with older versions of the Build Process Template, so I just changed the build to use TfvcTemplate.12.xaml and still no packages are restored. This latest change (from the link above) had me delete the NuGet.targets file and now I get an error saying:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer.
Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is 
:\Builds\TFS\WebApps\src\WebApps\Main\Src\\.nuget\NuGet.targets.
```

Comment: Same here, except I never had a `nuget.targets` to begin with. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I did find this.  We have a shared network folder that acts as a cache for NuGet packages; if I hand-edit the project files and point the `HintPath`s at this network folder, that seems to work.  But it is ugly, and doesn't answer why the restore isn't working in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tried so many solutions based on google. Which may make your environment complex and confusing.

First there are two ways to do the nuget restore **MSBuild-integrated restore** and **Automatic restore in Visual Studio**. There are totally different things.

> With NuGet 2.7 and later, Visual Studio automatically restores missing
>   packages by default at the beginning of a build.

Since you are using NuGet 3.4, suggest you to use Automatic restore.

You could only select one way to do the restore operation. Based your error message NuGet.targets not found, maybe you haven't finished [**Migrating to automatic restore**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) step. Please do it again or double check this.

You could also test the migration, do the following:

- **Remove the packages folder** from the solution.
- Open the solution in Visual Studio and start a build.
- Automatic restore should download and install each dependency
  package, without adding them to source control.

Do not add  `$(SolutionDir).nuget\nuget.exe restore -SolutionDirectory ..\` to the pre-build event on my first project in the build order . This is the old way to do the restore. Just like the way describe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/team-foundation-build).

Nuget Restore.exe was added to the 2013 (v12) templates. Since you are using the `TfvcTemplate.12.xaml` , you don't have to add it again.

Highly doubt you were mixing up the two ways cause your present dilemma. Suggest you follow the automatic restore process, use a clean environment, complete migration to automatic restore step , test the migration locally, make sure NuGet.exe and NuGet.targets files from .nuget folder in source control are removed, checking pending changes, check your `TfvcTemplate.12.xaml` Process Templates with Nuget Restore functionality. Create a new build definition with old settings and use the template. Finally trigger the build...

Comment: Your 'Migrating to Automatic Restore' link is broken: the page is correct, but the migration anchor no longer exists.