# MSBuild not restoring NuGet packages

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution consisting of multiple projects, several of which reference NuGet packages.  There's a web site but also a service which has to be built for x86 or x64; the service is what I'm currently trying to build.

We're on TFS 2013; for this particular solution, I'm using Visual Studio 2015. 
 "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during Visual Studio build" are both checked.
I was running NuGet 3.4.4, I've updated to 4.6.2.

I can build fine from Visual Studio.  But automated builds on the server fail; but more importantly, it also fails if I try to run MSBuild locally.  Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680811/the-command-c-main-src-nuget-nuget-exe-restore-solutiondirectory-exited) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700823/nuget-auto-package-restore-just-will-not-work-for-me-on-my-build-server/).

As far as I can tell, the release template is the correct version (12), but I don't think it's a server issue, since I can't build locally either.

The packages are not in source control.
I have a `nuget.config` in the solution root folder; it previously was in a `.nuget` folder under the solution root.  I do not (and never did) have `nuget.exe` or `nuget.targets` in the `nuget` folder.  Here's the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGetCache" value="\\BuildServer\NuGetPackages" />
    <add key="NuGetV2" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true"/>
  </solution>
</configuration>
```

If I (manually) clear the packages and run

```
MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64
```

(from a VS2015 command prompt), it fails, because it can't find the referenced packages.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690012/654199), I've removed the `EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports` targets from my projects; they did not have a `RestorePackages` tag or an import for `nuget.targets`.

I tried adding a pre-build event to do the package restore (yes, I realize this is the "old" way of doing things)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\nuget.exe" restore -ConfigFile "$(SolutionDir)nuget.config" -PackagesDirectory "$(SolutionDir)packages"
```

... but it consistently fails ("The command exited with code 1").  If I copy the NuGet command line from the MSBuild output and execute it on its own, it succeeds.

I have noticed one odd thing: in the pre-build event, NuGet says "The folder  d:\path\to\solution\project1\bin\Release-x64 does not contain an msbuild solution   or packages.config file to restore".  I'm not sure why it's looking for those in the output folder.

---

I do have a workaround for this.  We have a network share set up to use as sort of a package cache.  If I hand-edit the project files and change each reference so that the `HintPath` points to `\\BuildServer\NuGetPackages\` rather than `..\packages\`, the build will succeed.  But this is ugly, and more importantly it significantly degrades the performance of Visual Studio.

Comment: Since you are using Visual Studio 2015, `nuget restore the_solution.sln` is the right way to go, but it should be the very first step of your build script, not something hidden in `PreBuild`. That's not old at all, and unless you are doing .NET Core in VS2017.